# How do I properly split apart a Controller's model?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm working on a webapp to teach myself Ember, and I've walked into one large issue:

The page halts while it is attempting to fetch json, and my IndexRoute and IndexController feel very bloated. Additionally, `this.store.find('pokemon')` uses the RESTAdapater, and can freeze the page from rendering anything (besides the loader) for up to 1.5 seconds.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {

            var store = this.store;
            return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            pokeballs: App.Pokeball.all(),
            pokemon: store.find('pokemon'),
            status: App.Status.all(),
            levels: App.Levels
        });
    }
});
```

**Updated Question:** As it is now, my IndexController is [larger than I would like](https://github.com/TheIronDeveloper/pokemon-catch-rate/blob/0244aeaf52237605bf4aebd7e13e82c54b3eea5d/scripts/app.js#L45-L113), and is acting as a mediator for the pokeballs and pokemon collections. I am thinking it would be a good idea to split up IndexController so that I have an IndexController, a PokemonListController, and a PokeballListController. The problems I have are:

1. How should I populate the content of the PokemonListController and PokeballListController if I am on '/', which maps to the IndexRoute?
2. Is this actually a good idea, am I treating controller's they way they are intended to be treated?

Webapp Demo: http://theirondeveloper.github.io/pokemon-catch-rate

Github: https://github.com/TheIronDeveloper/pokemon-catch-rate

Comment: At a glance it looks like the find is your only real async call - unless the App.Status.all()/levels/Pokeballs.all() are async also ... (if you ONLY need 1 async call here you could just return that directly but if that is causing the true 1.5 sec delay you might still see some jank.) Have you look at the network tab in chrome to see what the latency looks like for each async part of this?

Comment: Yes, the only async call is the `store.find()`. I did try returning the .find() directly, but I was not a fan of having to add an observer to check for the change of length of the `model.pokemon` (it felt wrong.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Not seeing anything "bloated" about your `IndexRoute` or `IndexController`. It is true that a lot of Ember apps will have multiple routes and thus multiple controllers, but that happens when it makes sense to switch to other routes. If it doesn't make sense for your application - then what you have is great.
2. If you have multiple routes (and thus multiple controllers), the approach @Asgaroth suggested will work great for setting multiple controllers. Otherwise, if you only have a single route - there is really no need to have multiple controllers.
3. The fact that your data gets fetched and that takes some time is normal. Now, ideally this (data fetching) should only happen once and your data would then get cached and as you peruse around your other routes (which you currently do not have) your data would already be available to you without any extra penalty.
4. If you do need to have multiple controllers and are wondering how to communicate between them, you are probably looking for the `needs API` outlined [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/dependency-injection-and-service-lookup/#toc_lightweight-services-with-code-needs-code).

**UPDATE**

I took another look at the `model` hook and it *is* weird how 3 out of 4 things in there are not promises at all and don't look like they belong in there.

So, here is how you can clean that up.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('pokemon');
  }
});
```

That's the only thing that belongs in there. The other properties might as well be properties on your controller, as in:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  levels: function(){
    return App.Levels; 
  }.property(),
  pokeballs: function(){
    return App.Pokeball.all()
  }.property(),
  status: function(){
    return App.Status.all();
  }.property(),
```

Of course, you would then need to change references to those properties in your template and other code. So, for example, you would change from `model.pokeballs` to just `pokeballs`. You would also change from `model.pokemon` to just `model`

I submitted a pull request to show you the way I did this - see [here](https://github.com/TheIronDeveloper/pokemon-catch-rate/pull/1)

Answer (score 2):

On one hand you are not tied to a single controller in a route, there is generally only a single controller associated with a route, but you can always set more controllers if you need them to, remember they are decorators of your models.

```
 App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
     model: function() {
        return store.find('pokemon');
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
      var pokemonListController = this.controllerFor('pokemons');
      var pokeballListController = this.controllerFor('pokeball');


      controller.set('model', model); //this would be the index controller

      pokemonListController.set('model', model.pokemon);
      pokeballListController.set('model', model.pokeballs);
    }
 });
```

Also you can render your page if you need to, without waiting for the responses, Ember will handle updating your UI once the response is received. if your response is too slow, the user will see the page, and an empty list (in this case, empty list of pokemon), and then once the request is resolved, the list will fill up with it.

To do that, just return an empty array from your model hook, and update it async:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
      var pokemon = [];
      var store = this.store;

      store.find('pokemon').then(function(allPokemon) {
        pokemon = allPokemon; //untested, you may need to push them instead
      });

      return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        pokeballs: App.Pokeball.all(),
        pokemon: pokemon,
        status: App.Status.all(),
        levels: App.Levels
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: Would you be able to suggest a pattern for mediating data between Controllers?

Comment: Can you elaborate? @TheIronDeveloper?

Comment: Sure. Right now my IndexController watches all UI behavior, and manages the relationship between the other sets of data. Breaking up the data into multiple Controllers seems ideal, however the IndexController loses access to the other models this way..

Comment: But does the index controller still need access to them? Depending on the king of logic you are handling, you can put that logic in the route instead, if it is ui logic it would go in the respective controller. Rember you still have two way data binding to help you should you need it

Comment: My IndexController has a series of observers that alters the pokeball list and current visible pokemon ( [see here](https://github.com/TheIronDeveloper/pokemon-catch-rate/blob/0244aeaf52237605bf4aebd7e13e82c54b3eea5d/scripts/app.js#L45-L113) )

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer, but to reveal the magic between the route and controller ... here is how the model gets drop'd into the controller instance for you

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return store.fin('pokemon');
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        //the model that gets returned from the above method is added to the controller instance for you in this generated method on the route
        controller.set('model', model); //also alias'd as content in older versions of ember
    }
});
```